# Use PayPal iOS SDK with WooCommerce

Tags: php, ios, swift, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on iOS app using **XCode 8.2.1** and **Swift 3.0** for a WooCommerce Store website.

What I am trying to do is to allow the user to pay for the order using PayPal iOS SDK inside the app then after receiving the payment success confirmation from the SDK programatically add the order to WooCommerce as paid using PayPal without the need to login to wordpress and proceed to checkout by the user, how to achieve this approach?

Here is my code to create the order on WooCommerce:-

```
try {
    $api = WC()->api->WC_API_Orders;
    $orderData = $api->create_order($this->data);
    $order = $orderData["order"];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log("Caught $e");
}
```

Here is the swift code from the paypal ios sdk once the payment succeeded:-

```
func payPalPaymentViewController(_ paymentViewController: PayPalPaymentViewController, didComplete completedPayment: PayPalPayment) {
    print("PayPal Payment Success !")
    paymentViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        // send completed confirmaion to your server
        print("Here is your proof of payment:\n\n\(completedPayment.confirmation)\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.")

        self.resultText = completedPayment.description
        self.showSuccess()
    })
}
```

Comment: The moment you spoke of iOS and *anything* other than Apple? I know you won't be approved.

Comment: According to App Store Review Guidelines on this
link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/
3.1.5 Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than IAP to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry. Apps may facilitate transmission of approved virtual currencies (e.g. Bitcoin, DogeCoin) provided that they do so in compliance with all state and federal laws for the territories in which the app functions.

Comment: The WooCommerce store which I am building iOS app for is selling physical goods so I must user payments methods other than App in app purchase

Comment: Well, good luck with having Apple not get their 30% cut.